# Using text such as "x" as a div border

Tags: css, border

I'd like to use the letter "x" as a repeating bottom border on a div. Is this possible? Am I going to have to convert the text to an image and use the border-image property instead?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a bottom container that you fill up with `x` characters using javascript. Something like this would work:

```
.container {
   position:relative;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   padding:16px;
   background-color:yellow;
}
.bottom {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   width:100%;
   background-color:red;
 }

 $(document).ready(function() {
     var width = $('.bottom').width();
     var chars = Math.round(width / 2); /* you need to tweek this */
     var characters = new Array(chars).join('x');
     $('.bottom').text(characters);
 });


 <div class="container">
   <div class="bottom"></div>
 </div>
```

I was also thinking about using the pseudo-element `:after` doing something like this:

```
 .container:after {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-12px;
    left:0;
    background-color:green;
    width:100%;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    content:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
 }
 <div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, but you must give us an code example and an more explicit questions.

```
<div style="border-bottom:<?php echo $x;?>px;">123</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using the CSS `:after` pseudo-attribute, with a `content` property.

See this JSFiddle for an example:  http://jsfiddle.net/matthewg0/0uhm08o0/

It uses the following CSS to achieve the result you are looking for using only CSS (no javascript).

```
.x-separator:after {
    content:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    font-size:10px;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```